# Few HTTP headers missing for the request sent via java

Tags: java, http, http-headers

I wrote a simple program in Java that sends an HTTP `GET` request to a URL, reads the response, and shows the headers from that response in the console. Here is my code:

```
        URL url= new URL(textBox.getText());
        socket = new Socket(url.getAuthority(), DEFAULT_PORT);
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        writer.println("GET "  + url.getFile() + " HTTP/1.1");
        writer.println("Host: " + url.getAuthority());
        writer.println("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0");
        writer.println("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
      writer.println("");
        writer.flush();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
            if (line.isEmpty()) break;
            response.append(line + "\n");
        }
```

The web server sets multiple cookies, but my code is displaying only the first few `Set-cookie` headers.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For loading a webpage, browser will send a series of HTTP requests. You might be sending only first request via java code. If the same request is sent via some Web browser, it will render the loaded page and will trigger the further HTTP requests. These subsequent requests might set the remaining cookies.

I suggest you to compare the both the responses (sent via Java code and Browser) , you can use [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for this.

Comment: ok i examine the traffic between firefox and some webserver using HttpFox and you are right.... thank you